# Any ideas on why i am receiving this error? Any help appreciated. Thnx

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

```
Uninstalling : 
The term 'C:\temp\install\Deploy-Application.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp\install\Deploy-Application.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : WKPF26YSKX
```

This is the code ran:

```
function Install-File {
    Invoke-Command `
        -Session $global:session `
        -ScriptBlock{ 
        
    if( -not (Test-Path -Path "V:\") ) {
                New-PSDrive -Name "V" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\lounaswps01\idrive\D907ATS" -Credential (Get-Credential -Credential "slb8031a") -Scope global

            } 
         

            $Global:certRequestID = $global:objTemp.CRID

        # Assign server path and local path variables w/ given CR ID
             $serverPath = "v:\" + $Global:certRequestID
            $localPath = "C:\temp\" + $Global:certRequestID

          
            dir $serverPath
            dir $localPath

          
          #Copy-Item -Path $serverPath -Destination $localPath -Recurse -Force | Out-Host
            

        # Check for atsinst.bat first - run it if it exists. Else offer uninstall/install options
            
                if(Test-Path -LiteralPath "${localPath}\install\atsinst.bat") {
                    Invoke-Expression -Command " ${localPath}\install\atsinst.bat -DeployMode 'Silent'  | Out-Host "
                }

                
                    Write-Host "`nUninstalling ${certRequestID}: "
                    Invoke-Expression -Command " ${localPath}install\Deploy-Application.exe -DeployMode 'Silent' -DeploymentType 'Uninstall'  | Out-Host"
                    #Start-process -FilePath "${localPath}\install\Deploy-Application.exe" -argumentList "-DeployMode Silent -DeploymentType Uninstall" -wait -noNewWindow

                
                    Write-Host "`nInstalling ${certRequestID}: "
                    Invoke-Expression -Command " ${localPath}\install\Deploy-Application.exe -DeployMode 'Silent'  | Out-Host "
                    
            }
        # Offer to delete files from host
             $prompt = Read-Host -Prompt "`nDelete ${certRequestID} from the user's temp folder? (y/n)"
            if($prompt.ToLower() -eq "y") {
                Write-Host "`nDeleting files..."
                Remove-Item -LiteralPath $localPath -Recurse -Force  
        }
        }
```

Comment: Well, it indicates that `$global:objTemp.CRID` resolves to `$null` or an empty string in the remote session. Looks like something (another function perhaps?) is supposed to run against the remote session to set up these values first?

Comment: Yeah its supposed to install software in the remote sessions. So "C:\temp\install\Deploy-Application.exe" should be "C:\temp\SOFTWARE\install\Deploy-Application.exe" but it isnt pulling the CRID for some reason @MathiasR.Jessen Appreciate ur help

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a backslash in one of the lines for uninstalling?

```
Invoke-Expression -Command " ${localPath}install\Deploy-Application.exe
```

Should Read:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command " ${localPath}\install\Deploy-Application.exe
```